# Rajawali rotating camera with Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR strange behavior

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, android-sensors, rajawali

I'm creating a Panorama view which allows the user to look around in a spherical image by rotating his smartphone. I used Rajawali's Skybox for this together with the TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR sensor.

I got it working, but only when I look forward (it's literally based on my rotation (yaw))

This is the behavior:

- looking forward: yaw = yaw, pitch = pitch and roll = roll
- looking to the left: yaw = yaw, pitch = roll and roll = pitch
- looking backwards: yaw = yaw, pitch = pitch * -1 and roll = roll * -1.

Now I do have a hunch what is going on. It seems the "camera object" keeps looking at the same direction, even if it doesn't appear to. This means that pitching seems to be the same as rolling, but in stead it's still pitching because the object hasn't rotated. I'm comparing it to being in an airplane and looking around.

What do I need to do to solve this?

I have a feeling I'm going to have to rotate the camera with lookAt(), but I'm not sure how.

```
public class SkyboxFragment extends RajawaliFragment implements SensorEventListener {

    public static final String TAG = "SkyBoxFragment";
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private float[] orientationVals = new float[3];
    private float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    private Sensor mRotVectSensor;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mRotVectSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);
        mLayout.addView(ll);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mRotVectSensor,
                10000);
        return mLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public AExampleRenderer createRenderer() {
        mRenderer = new SkyboxRenderer(getActivity());
        return ((SkyboxRenderer) mRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(mRotationMatrix, event.values);
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(mRotationMatrix, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, mRotationMatrix);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(mRotationMatrix, orientationVals);
            orientationVals[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[0]);
            orientationVals[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[1]) * -1;
            orientationVals[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientationVals[2]) * -1;
            //Log.d(TAG,  "YAW:" + orientationVals[0] + " PITCH:" + orientationVals[1] + "ROLL:" + orientationVals[2]);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    private final class SkyboxRenderer extends AExampleRenderer implements View.OnClickListener {

        private final Vector3 mAccValues;
        boolean odd = true;

        public SkyboxRenderer(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mAccValues = new Vector3();
        }

        @Override
        protected void initScene() {
            getCurrentCamera().setFarPlane(1000);
            /**
             * Skybox images by Emil Persson, aka Humus. http://www.humus.name humus@comhem.se
             */
            try {
                getCurrentScene().setSkybox(R.drawable.posx, R.drawable.negx,
                        R.drawable.posy, R.drawable.negy, R.drawable.posz, R.drawable.negz);
            } catch (ATexture.TextureException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRender(long ellapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
            super.onRender(ellapsedRealtime, deltaTime);
            getCurrentCamera().setRotation(orientationVals[2], orientationVals[0], orientationVals[1]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (odd) {
                    /**
                     * Skybox images by Emil Persson, aka Humus. http://www.humus.name humus@comhem.se
                     */
                    getCurrentScene().updateSkybox(R.drawable.posx2, R.drawable.negx2,
                            R.drawable.posy2, R.drawable.negy2, R.drawable.posz2, R.drawable.negz2);
                } else {
                    /**
                     * Skybox images by Emil Persson, aka Humus. http://www.humus.name humus@comhem.se
                     */
                    getCurrentScene().updateSkybox(R.drawable.posx, R.drawable.negx,
                            R.drawable.posy, R.drawable.negy, R.drawable.posz, R.drawable.negz);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                odd = !odd;
            }
        }

        public void setAccelerometerValues(float x, float y, float z) {
            mAccValues.setAll(-x, -y, -z);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is the problem you are describing, but another problem is that the sensor for `TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR` is affected by nearby magnets such as those found in phone cases.

## Solving the magnet problem

A solution could be to use a combination of the accelerometer and the gyroscope. Luckily, the [Google Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/download) already abstracted this away.

You can track the current rotation by instantiating an instance of `com.google.vrtoolkit.cardboard.sensors.HeadTracker` using `HeadTracker.createFromContext(this.getActivity())` and calling `startTracking()` on it.

Now you don't need `onSensorChanged` anymore. Instead, in your `onRender`, you can do this:

```
float[] R = new float[16];
headTracker.getLastHeadView(R, 0);
```

to get the rotation matrix. This solves your unstated problem of magnetic fields.

## Getting the camera to look around properly

The easiest way to use this rotation matrix to point the camera in the right direction is to convert it to an `org.rajawali3d.math.Quaternion` and then call `getCurrentCamera().setCameraOrientation(quaternion);`

The conversion from `float[16]` to a quaternion can be difficult to get right, but once again, the Google Cardboard SDK did it for you. In this case, it's in the source code of an old class that is no longer used: [HeadTransform](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Hardware/accelerometer/com_google_vrtoolkit_cardboardHeadTransform_java.htm).

You can easily adapt that code to `return new Quaternion(w, x, y, z);`.

Now this will result in the same issues as current code would have if you did not multiply `orientationVals[1]` and `orientationVals[2]` by `-1`.

That problem, however, is easily solved by inverting the rotation matrix. That would result in the following code in `onRender` (assuming `getQuaternion(R)` returns an `org.rajawali3d.math.Quaternion`):

```
@Override
protected void onRender(long ellapsedRealtime, double deltaTime) {
    super.onRender(ellapsedRealtime, deltaTime);

    float[] R = new float[16];
    headTracker.getLastHeadView(R, 0);

    android.opengl.Matrix.invertM(R, 0, R, 0);

    Quaternion q = getQuaternion(R);

    getCurrentCamera().setCameraOrientation(q);
}
```