# Rotate Rajawali camera using gyroscope and magnetic sensor

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-sensors, rajawali

I am developing an Augmented reality application with Rajawali lib. My problem is as below.

I want to draw a surface onto the camera view, when i tried the latest ver of rajawali, it didn't work. I spent many days and find out that the latest did not support draw over camera any more. And the rajawali v0.9 work fine. So the following question is apply for v0.9.

When i tried to register SensorEventListener, and in onSensorChanged() I got 3 values which represent 3 dimension of android device, but it was very noise and unstable. I have tried implement low-pass filter but it still noise. 
Finally i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35579964/rajawali-rotating-camera-with-sensor-type-rotation-vector-strange-behavior), but on v0.9, the

```
getCamera().setOrientation(quaternion)
```

did not work. I dont know why.
Now i don't know what to do next :(

Comment: did you finally got the solution?

Comment: No, but i dont work with it anymore :D you got that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my codes, it works very well in my project, and I hope it to help you.

// The code snippet of my renderer class

```
@Override
public void onRender(final long elapsedTime, final double deltaTime) {
    mHeadTracker.getLastHeadView(mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0);

    android.opengl.Matrix.invertM(mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0, mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0);

    Quaternion q = mHeadTransform.getQuaternion(mHeadTransform.getHeadView(), 0);

    getCurrentCamera().setOrientation(q);

    super.onRender(elapsedTime, deltaTime);
}
```

// The code snippet of HeadTransform class

```
private static Quaternion sQuaternion = new Quaternion();
public Quaternion getQuaternion(float[] quaternion, int offset) {
    if (offset + 4 > quaternion.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Not enough space to write the result");
    }
    float[] m = this.mHeadView;
    float t = m[0] + m[5] + m[10];
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float w;
    float s;
    if (t >= 0.0F) {
        s = (float) Math.sqrt(t + 1.0F);
        w = 0.5F * s;
        s = 0.5F / s;
        x = (m[9] - m[6]) * s;
        y = (m[2] - m[8]) * s;
        z = (m[4] - m[1]) * s;
    } else {
        if ((m[0] > m[5]) && (m[0] > m[10])) {
            s = (float) Math.sqrt(1.0F + m[0] - m[5] - m[10]);
            x = s * 0.5F;
            s = 0.5F / s;
            y = (m[4] + m[1]) * s;
            z = (m[2] + m[8]) * s;
            w = (m[9] - m[6]) * s;
        } else {
            if (m[5] > m[10]) {
                s = (float) Math.sqrt(1.0F + m[5] - m[0] - m[10]);
                y = s * 0.5F;
                s = 0.5F / s;
                x = (m[4] + m[1]) * s;
                z = (m[9] + m[6]) * s;
                w = (m[2] - m[8]) * s;
            } else {
                s = (float) Math.sqrt(1.0F + m[10] - m[0] - m[5]);
                z = s * 0.5F;
                s = 0.5F / s;
                x = (m[2] + m[8]) * s;
                y = (m[9] + m[6]) * s;
                w = (m[4] - m[1]) * s;
            }
        }
    }
    quaternion[(offset + 0)] = x;
    quaternion[(offset + 1)] = y;
    quaternion[(offset + 2)] = z;
    quaternion[(offset + 3)] = w;

    Log.d("facevr", x + "," + y + "," + z + "," + w);

    return sQuaternion.setAll(w, x, y, z);
}
```